# Load balancing when Docker Swarm is combined with Spring Cloud Eureka/Gateway

Tags: spring, docker, spring-cloud, docker-swarm, netflix-eureka

I have a question regarding how Load balancing works when you have a single node Docker Swarm combined with Spring Eureka using Spring Cloud gateway.  I have successfully configured a non Eureka swarm and can see Swarm load balancing between replicas for a service:

```
Cloud Gateway route config    
.route(r -> r.path("/api/**")
                            .uri("http://my-service:8081")
                            .id("my-service"))
```

If I then configure this to use Eureka I now have this:

```
.route(r -> r.path("/api/**")
                                .uri("lb://MY-SERVICE")
                                .id("my-service"))
```

I believe I'm right in assuming that the gateway will know the IP/Ports and load balance accordingly, however when a request hits an IP will swarm then also decide to load balance between the replicas?

I appreciate that Eureka may be overkill for a small single node swarm but feel it could be beneficial as the app expands and possibly becomes more distributed.  Obviously I want to avoid a situation where load balancing happens twice.

I assume I could just use `http` instead of `lb` to stop the Gateway from load balancing.

Comment: So I think I found the answer.  I found the container IPs for my replicas and updated the Gateway to route to one of the IPs.  I swarm service updated the Gateway service and then checked the logs of each replicated service.  Only the container with the IP in Gateway was being hit.  Therefore I'm confident that using Eureka will not cause multiple load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

The eureka discovery service will provide the api gateway all available addresses for a given service. Each service registered within eureka will have a unique (container) IP and port and if the api gateway is configured to load balance the requests then yes, each replica of the service will be used, swarm doesn't need to do anything for load balancing, since you are targeting a specific running service (task) and not a node, for example.

However, for a multi-node scenario, Docker swarm has a routing mesh functionality that basically removes the need of having a discovery service. Imagine you have multiple nodes and replicas distributed across them. With swarm's routing mesh you don't even have to know which nodes have specific services running. The api gateway can route the incoming request to literally any node, and if that node happens to lack the requested service, it will automatically balance the request to nodes that do have the task (the name given to a running service).

So, that means that the load balancer doesn't need any sort of discovery service such as Eureka in order to balance the requests to certain container's IPs or nodes, it can simply round-robin all available nodes and that's it.

As for internal requests between the services that have replicas, swarm also provides load balancing capabillities.